# Aligning math equation without getting equation numbers

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to present a multi-line equation, but the align function includes equation numbers, which does not make sense in my case. How can I remove them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
u(k) = u(k-1) + K_{R} \cdot (1 + \frac{T_{0}}{2\cdot T_{I}}) \cdot e(k) &- K_{R} \cdot (1+2\cdot \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}}-\frac{T_{0}}{2\cdot T_{I}}) \cdot e(k-1) \\ & + K_{R}\cdot \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}} \cdot e(k-2) 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `align*` instead of `align`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `campa` statement, please use `align*` instead of `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
u(k) &= u(k-1) + K_{R} \cdot (1 + \frac{T_{0}}{2\cdot T_{I}}) \cdot e(k) - K_{R} \cdot (1+2\cdot \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}}-\frac{T_{0}}{2\cdot T_{I}}) \cdot e(k-1) \\ 
&\quad + K_{R}\cdot \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}} \cdot e(k-2) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic: I have changed the alignment as per standard format, made the second line with `\quad` space indent with respect to the first line

Comment: You might also try `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} 1 &= 2 \\ &= 3 \end{aligned}\end{equation}` for alignment within an equation that is only numbered once.